# Remote Desktop Web client

Tags: rdp, mstsc

I have few Cloud based Windows box connected with internet and I wanted to access the same from my office network.

The problem here is, my office doesn't allow direct RDP to any internet connected pc as we normally access all sites using proxy.

Is there anyway I can connect through web based client? I tried TSWEB/RDWEB but again it seems using local port number.

Any suggestion?

Thanks
bala

Comment: Question is not clear for me.. as i got you a in a network that uses NAT so you need to traverse it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another client "ThinRDP" which works as expected. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try Igiko Management Tools and forget about such problems. It has embedded Web RDP + Gateway + Tunnel. Works from anywhere.